# Unidirectional one-to-one mapping hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, one-to-one, join

I have a database which which contains three tables, 'User', 'Address' and 'ContactDetails'.

```
'User' Table
    - Id
    - Username

'Address' Table
    - Id
    - Type ('1' for a home address, '2' for a work address)
    - Address

'ContactDetails' Table
    - Id
    - Email address
```

The Id for a particular user in the 'User' table corresponds to the Id in both the 'Address' and the 'ContactDetails' tables.

I want to use hibernate to join these tables together as a single User object with the following variables:

```
private int id;
private Address homeAddress; // ie where Type = 1
private Address businessAddress; // ie where Type = 2
private ContactDetails contactDetails;
```

I currently have User, Address and ContactDetails mapped into classes, but I am struggling to pull them together into a single class with the above structure.

Could somebody give me a quick example of how the relationships could be mapped using annotations? I don't want to change the classes Address or ContactDetails to contain a variable of the type 'User' as I will only be accessing a users Address or ContactDetails through the User class. I can't alter the database unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@Embeddable` annotations with `@AttributeOverride` to force the embedded entities to be persisted in their own table.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables